# Angular.js filter shows only 20 elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-filter

I am new to `angularjs` . Here, I am using a filter , I have a list of elements . And I have one `searchBox` . So, Here

```
<li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="suggestion in suggestionList | filter:suggestionListSearchText | limitTo: -20 track by $index"
```

Here, I have not added the ending `li tag` . Now, When I open the list that time it shows the last `20 elements` which is correct. But When I search where search is happening over the list items, That timw if I search for an element `n` then it gives me only 20 elements which has the word `n`  and not all the elements . So, Can any one tell me the reason behind this ?

Comment: There is a limitTo attribute on that filter

Comment: Thats what [`limitTo`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/limitTo) do

Comment: Yes, But I just want to have that filter on the suggestion while showing all the list and when I search then It should show all the elements, It should not be on the searching.

Answer (score 0):

First, you can assign the `limitTo` value to variable using `ng-init`

```
<li ng-init="limit = 20" class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="suggestion in suggestionList | filter:suggestionListSearchText | limitTo: limit track by $index">
```

In the search input use ng-change along with the ternary operation to assign `limit` variable.

```
<input  ng-model="suggestionListSearchText" ng-change="limit = ( suggestionListSearchText ? '' : 20 )" />
```